# Looking for pythonic way to sort and count unique by colum of csv file

Tags: python-2.7

Essentially I'm trying to do sort by the 4th column on a csv file and count the unique occurrences.  I've accomplished this in bash with the below:  Is there a pythonic way to accomplish this?

```
   $ cat myfile.csv
a,t,f,5
f,b,j,5
f,d,p,4
d,t,l,4
f,k,y,2
g,k,t,2
j,r,f,1
l,g,h,2
g,g,k,5
r,k,k,1

$ awk -F , '{print $4}' myfile.csv | sort | uniq -c
      2 1
      3 2
      2 4
      3 5
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would open the file and create a list containing the value from the forth column in each line.

Once I have this list I would loop over it printing the unique value and the count of each unique value in the list.

Next I would ensure that I don't repeat over any value and that I print the values in order. To accomplish this i use the `set()` and `sorted()` built-in python functions.

The code I would write would look something like this, where `****` is the filename.

```
myFile = open(****,'r')
myValues = [value.split(',')[3] for value in myFile.readlines()]
for uniqueValue in sorted(set(myValues)):
    print "%s : %s" % (uniqueValue,myValues.count(uniqueValue)
myFile.close()
```

Read more about `set()`, `sorted()`, and other built in python functions here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html.

You can change the python version in the top left corner of the documents.